# Entity Framework + Fluent API + Web API?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Estou com problemas para mapear a categoria dentro de um produto, quando listo os produtos a categoria (`virtual class`) vem vazia, mesmo com `CategoryId` preenchido.

#### Product

```
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        this.LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Title;
    }
}
```

#### Product Map

```
public class ProductMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{

    public ProductMap()
    {
        ToTable("Product");
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        Property(x => x.Title).HasMaxLength(160).IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.Price).IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.LastUpdate).IsRequired();

        HasRequired(x => x.Category);

    }
}
```

#### Category

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Title;
    }
}
```

#### Category Map

```
public class CategoryMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Category>
{
    public CategoryMap()
    {
        ToTable("Category");
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        Property(x => x.Title).HasMaxLength(60).IsRequired();

        HasMany<Product>(x => x.Products).WithRequired(c => c.Category);
    }
}
```

#### GetProducts

```
// GET: api/Product
public IQueryable<Product> GetProducts()
{
    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    return db.Products;
}
```

#### Retorno

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Title": "Produto Eletrônico",
    "Price": 10010,
    "LastUpdate": "2015-10-29T18:28:19.547",
    "CategoryId": 1,
    "Category": null
}
```

Comment: Em CategoryMap, retire  o HasMany e no productMap, mude para HasRequired(x => x.Category).WithMany(x => x.Products).HasForeignKey(x => x.CategoryId);

Comment: Resolvido o problema?

Answer (score 1):

Tente alterar o seu método com:

```
public IQueryable<Product> GetProducts()
{
    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    var query = from r in db.Products.Include("Category") select r;
    return query;
}
```